# How to delete a certificate?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, certificate

I need to delete a certificate that is causing problems. Is there any method or development tool that can do this?

I'm pretty sure the certificate causing problems shipped with the phone, however it is the wrong one. The correct certificate, which only differs by "friendly name", is here: https://cloud.securew2.com/public/28503/eduroam/certificates/addtrustexternalca.cer You can see how this is installed by opening that file and cancelling out of the install screen. I believe the problem I'm experiencing is caused by the incorrect friendly name. Since they both have the same fingerprint, The phone happens to choose the one it shipped with, and I get rejected by the authenticating service

Answer (score 6):

Good luck with that, you will need to factory reset. There is an app on the Store called "Certificates" but it only allows you to view certs.